# Shiny app not closing when deployed

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app, something like this:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

runApp(
  list(
    ui = shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                dashboardHeader(title = "dashboard",
                                tags$li(a(onclick = "setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 100); ",
                                          icon("power-off", "fa-2x"),
                                          title = "Power off"),
                                        class = "dropdown")),
                dashboardSidebar(width='250px'),
                dashboardBody()
      )
    ),

    server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
      })
    })),
  launch.browser = TRUE)
```

The close button works when I run locally in a browser, but NOT in the internal Rstudio browser.

When I deploy it, the button does not work:

http://35.158.77.79/testclose/

Finally, if I deploy it at shinyapps.io, the close button works!

Anyone have an idea on what's the problem? javascript?

Comment: works fine in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: i think he means the internal preview of RStudio for which it is not working,...

Comment: Why don't you just let the user close it with the x?

Comment: App locally: chrome WORKS, firefox: NOT, internal rstudio browser: NOT

Comment: App deployed at my server: chrome NOT, firefox: NOT

Comment: App deployed at shinyapps.io: chrome WORKS, firefox: NOT